# updating JSON issue, how to correctly update?

Tags: node.js, json, express, server, filesystems

I have a file issueData.json and I want to update in POST request. This is my code. 
I try to read the file parse to array, push the new, and after it re-write.

```
app.post("/api/issues", (req, res, next) => {
  const issueObj = req.body;
  fs.readFile("issuesData.json", (err: Error, data: string | Buffer) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      const stringData = data.toString();
      const issueFile = [...JSON.parse(stringData)];
      const updatedIssueFile = issueFile.push(issueObj);
      fs.writeFile(
        "issuesData.json",
        JSON.stringify(updatedIssueFile),
        (err: Error) => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
          } else {
            res.status(200).send("Issue has updated");
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
});
```

1) Is it a good practice?
2) Is TS so, what should be the type of req, res, next?
3) It is a good way to update the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just writing to a file, you might not need to read the contents of the file and append your issueObj to the issueFile array. Maybe you could just write the issueObj to a new line in your file. Maybe something like the appendFile function would help (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback).

Currently, as your file grows, the read operations will take longer and longer and will affect performance. However, just writing will ensure you don't incur that overhead for each POST request.

Comment: ahh ok, for reading I made a pagination. So appendFile is like "push"?

Comment: Note i want to add to the last because in the JSON i have an array of Issues
[{id:....},
insert here]

Comment: appendFile will just write to a new line at the end of file. In that sense it sort of like "push", but to clarify it just writes strings to files. You can stick to an array of JSON in your file, however, I think it may be better to just write each JSON object on a new line. Then when you need to process that information, read in the file line-by-line and append it to an array then. There's no need to keep the data in an array structure in the file, right?